# Как выбрать 3-ёх самых дорогостоящих сотрудников за последние 2 года

Tags: sql-server

В общем есть таблица с тремя полями: [name] nvarchar(50) null, [createdDate] date null, [sum] money null. Требуется выбрать трёх сотрудников кому за определённый период времени выплатили наибольшую сумму.
 Знаю как задать запрос на выбор суммы выплат за определённый временной интервал, пример:

```
select SUM([tst_temp].[sum]) as [сумма] from dbo.tst_temp
where createdDate >= '19800101' and createdDate <= '20160801' and [name] = 'Иванов';
```

Знаю, что нужно использовать **ТОР()** и **GROUP BY** чтобы отсортировать и выбрать нужные значения. Но как составить итоговый запрос ни как не пойму...
Помогите пожалуйста.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Группируй по name.

```
select TOP 3 [tst_temp].[name], SUM([tst_temp].[sum]) as [сумма] from dbo.tst_temp
where createdDate >= '19800101' and createdDate <= '20160801'
group by [tst_temp].[name]
order by [сумма] desc
```

Как-то так.

Comment: Спасибо **privod**, не ожидал, что так легко можно. Думал уже курсор приспособить. В последней строке только [сумма], а не [tst_temp].[sum]. Ещё раз спасибо за помощь.